# Firebase hosting gives error Error: could not handle the request

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am using **firebase hosting** for the purpose of getting a google spreadsheet data using node js API. It works well if i fetch 1000 rows  but when i fetch 10000, it give me error *Error: could not handle the request*.

Below is the url with 1000 request
https://us-central1-valuemyplace-1525346661329.cloudfunctions.net/app/spreadsheet

Below is the url with 10000 request
https://us-central1-valuemyplace-1525346661329.cloudfunctions.net/app/test

Here is my code

```
function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: '1Lpbx-LQQTh-lF2E1lQmPnqZhvT2bWfQ9gxBX-qGBz_M',
    range: 'A1:P120933',
    //valueRenderOption: 'UNFORMATTED_VALUES'
    //majorDimension: 'COLUMNS'
  }, (err, {data}) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const rows = data.values;
    if (rows.length) {
      rows.map((row) => {
        const zipObj = (arr1, arr2, obj) => {
          if (arr1.length === 0 || arr2.length === 0) { return 0; }
          obj[arr1[0]] = arr2[0];
          return zipObj(arr1.slice(1), arr2.slice(1), obj);
        }

        const ress = [];

        for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
          let obj = {};
          zipObj(data.values[0], data.values[i], obj);
          ress.push(obj);
        }

        //console.log(res);
        firebase.database().ref().set(ress);
        res.send(ress);
       // console.log(row.length);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No data found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those URLs make it look like you're using Cloud Functions, not Firebase Hosting.

Comment: It wokrs well on localhost, but when i deploy to hosting it gives me error.

Comment: @DougStevenson but it works with 1000 rows request. Why is it not work with 10000? Even it works on localhost mamchine.

Comment: So here's a funny thing. The 1000 row request gives me an error but the 10,000 row one works fine.

Comment: @Jay on the first link i fetched 10,000 rows and on second link i fetched 1000 by mistake now check. and if you know how to solve this, please help me.

Comment: There's a problem with your code causing the error. However, since we don't have your code we won't know where the issue is. Please review the following guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post your code and we'll take a look.

Comment: But it works with 1000 of records

Comment: But we your code is still not included so we can't even begin to help. It may work sometimes because that's how it's coded, or maybe a asynchronous timing issue or a number of other things. You'll notice the question has downvotes (not me) and will most likely be closed because it's incomplete. We need to see your code and a snippet of your Firebase structure (as TEXT) to begin determining what the issue is.

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by myself using

```
function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: '1Lpbx-LQQTh-lF2E1lQmPnqZhvT2bWfQ9gxBX-qGBz_M',
    range: 'A1:P120933',
    //valueRenderOption: 'UNFORMATTED_VALUES'
    //majorDimension: 'COLUMNS'
  }, (err, {data}) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const rows = data.values;
    if (rows.length) {
      ** //rows.map((row) => {** *Do comment here*
        const zipObj = (arr1, arr2, obj) => {
          if (arr1.length === 0 || arr2.length === 0) { return 0; }
          obj[arr1[0]] = arr2[0];
          return zipObj(arr1.slice(1), arr2.slice(1), obj);
        }

        const ress = [];

        for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
          let obj = {};
          zipObj(data.values[0], data.values[i], obj);
          ress.push(obj);
        }

        //console.log(res);
        firebase.database().ref().set(ress);
        res.send(ress);
       // console.log(row.length);
      **//});** *Comment Here*
    } else {
      console.log('No data found.');
    }
  });
}
```